# Component in a ngFor - how to have the service grab that exact element?

Tags: angular

I have a service that is calling `this.lineChartService.makeGraph()` for the each chart in `*ngFor="let chart of charts | async | daysFilter: 7"`. In the service it does `document.querySelector('.graph-sheet')`. The issue is, the service isn't applied to the chart in a 1 to 1 encapsulation, it will grab the first graph instead in the document.

I broke this out of a angular 1 directive where this worked with no issues... the query selector always worked as intended by grabbing the chart it was apart of in the directive.

How can I use this same logic in a Angular 5 component? Where the queryselector will grab the component it is applied to in a isolated scope fashion?

last-seven-days.component.html

```
<div class="last-seven-days view" 
  *ngFor="let chart of charts | async | daysFilter: 7">
  <app-line-chart
    graphSize="med"
    [curveData]="chart"></app-line-chart>
</div>
```

---

line-chart.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { LineChartService } from '../line-chart.service';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-line-chart',
  template: '<div class="graph-sheet center"></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./line-chart.component.css']
})

export class LineChartComponent {
  @Input() graphSize: String;
  @Input() curveData: Array<object>;

  constructor(
    private lineChartService: LineChartService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lineChartService.makeGraph(
      this.graphSize,
      this.curveData
    );
  }
}
```

---

line-chart.service.ts

```
...
const divEl = document.querySelector('.graph-sheet')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take the reference of the view and pass it to the service, which the latter will use instead of the document, like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-line-chart',
  template: '<div class="graph-sheet center"></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./line-chart.component.css']
})
export class LineChartComponent {
  @Input() graphSize: String;
  @Input() curveData: Array<object>;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef
    private lineChartService: LineChartService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lineChartService.makeGraph(
      this.graphSize,
      this.curveData,
      this.elementRef.nativeElement
    );
  }
}
```

Than in your service:

```
const divEl = nativeELement.querySelector('.graph-sheet')
```

Just make sure you are not trying to select anything before the component has initialised(`ngOnInit`), which you don't in the specified example, but still.

**Note:**
In case the service is provided to the component through the means of the component itself and not some arbitrary module, the service also has reference to the same ElementRef the component does.

Comment: Can this be done with Render2 instead or a data binding? I read the warning form Angular about elementRef

Comment: It can be done with Render2, but just because you can access DOM with Render2 aswell. So it is basically the same. The warning you read is about accessing the DOM but this is the solution for what you are doing. Whether what you are doing is right or wrong it depends on what you are doing in a service. If you can provide more details about the service may be i can help with that.